# Put HTTP requests on 'hold' when redeploying JEE project

Tags: apache-2.2, http, jboss

We're using a JBoss server, which holds several projects. It is accessed through an Apache ProxyPass (basically `ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/`).

I am looking for a better way to redeploy a project without having visitors receiving a 404 from Apache (which does not find the java project running anymore). 
Would Apache be able to 'wait' and put those requests on 'hold' for a while when redeploying ?

Thanks,
Alexis.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you setup another virtual directory in JBoss with a friendly page that tells visitors the site is being updated.  Then change the ProxyPass config to point to the maintenance page and then update your site.  This also allows you to test the site to make sure it is working properly before redirecting requests in ProxyPass back to your other site.

Comment: Thanks for your point. Let's suppose the deployment will go well. Having a maintenance page would then lower the quality of the service, whereas putting requests on hold would simply make the visitors wait a bit. I understand what you're saying is what we should do, but there might be other solutions.

Comment: Well the ultimate solution would be to have a secondary node in that case.  That way you could simply direct all traffic to the secondary node and update the primary node, once complete you redirect back to the primary node and the clients would not experience any downtime, however this requires the use of shared session providers and many other little tools to manage the environment.

Comment: Alright the secondary node seems to be a good intermediate solution. I was hoping something like I imagined existed but I understand this is not a good way to do things.